# What is this sealant on my basement waterproofing system?

Tags: basement, waterproofing, caulk, sealant

I'm redoing my basement floor and have a plastic channel system protecting against water intrusion around the edge of my basement (I believe it's an "All-Dry Basement Systems" product, but not sure; it predates my tenancy).  Some of the sealant was damaged during removal of the old flooring.

I can't tell what the sealant is in order to replace it, though.  The material is hard and looks almost clay-like, unlike any caulk I've ever seen.

What is this sealant, and where can I get it?

[image: Damaged sealant]
[image: Close-up of damaged sealant]
[image: Undamaged sealant]

Comment: Note that old dried out caulk can be very brittle, this is probably just caulk that has outlived its useful life.

Comment: dow 975 looks like that dry

Comment: I wasn't able to find Dow 975, did you mean Dow 795?